# Simple CreateView returns 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Very simple CreateView is not working, and I do not know why:

view:

```
class CreateProduct(CreateView):
    template_name = "app/product_create2.html"
    form_class = ProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("index")
```

form:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ("description", "name", "price")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.field_class = 'mb-2'
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST' 
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success'))
```

urls:

```
path("create/", views.CreateProduct.as_view(), name = 'create'),
```

template:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form %}
</div>
```

When I input Data in the form I get:

> Method Not Allowed (POST): /

and I can seet the 405 error in the console.

From crispy forms created code in the template:

```
<form method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="..."> 
    <div id="div_id_description" class="form-group"> 
        <label for="id_description" class=" requiredField">Description</label> 
        <div class="mb-2"> 
            <input type="text" name="description" maxlength="128" class="textinput textInput form-control" required="" id="id_description">     
        </div> 
    </div> 
        ....
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="mb-2"> 
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-success" id="submit-id-submit"> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: It looks like your form is being posted to the incorrect url? Your url pattern is `create/` but in the error it only shows `/`.

Comment: yes exactly - but I don't get why? Where can I check that?

Comment: Are you by any chance rendering this form in the page with the url `/`?

Comment: yes! it is called via HTMX and opened as a modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this form is present in a different page than what it is supposed to post the data to one needs to set the forms action attribute. To do that with `crispy-forms` one can set the `form_action` attribute on the helper. You can do this in the forms `__init__` method itself or a better place would be the view's `get_form` method:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class CreateProduct(CreateView):
    template_name = "app/product_create2.html"
    form_class = ProductForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("index")
    
    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        form.helper.form_action = reverse('create')
        return form
```